# How to open a Python interpreter input cell?

Tags: cells, keyboard, external-calls, python

Something weird just happened to me: I mis-typed a keyboard shortcut, hitting the wrong keys, and a new notebook opened up with a Python prompt! Just for grins, I tried entering some simple Python code into the cell and evaluating it, and sure enough, it produced correct output.

[image]

The little python-logo box to the left of the input box, if clicked, produces a drop-down menu that lets me choose Python or NodeJS.

I've done some googling, and discovered that *Mathematica* has a new experimental "external evaluation system". Cool! However, I have been unable to figure out what keystroke I hit that made this little gem appear. All the *Mathematica* docs say is that one can use the relatively clumsy `ExternalEvaluate["Python",code]` expression.

Does anyone know how to produce this special input cell?

Comment: Type > at the start of an input cell

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Type > at the start of a cell (or when between cells).  This is documented in an example on ref/ExternalEvaluate (last Basic Example).  I'm a bit suprised it's not in the details section.  It probably should be...

Comment: Argh. I guess I should have scrubbed through the examples more carefully… I assumed to quickly that because it is an "experimental" feature, the keyboard shortcut would be undocumented.