# Can I stop the python interpreter appearing?

Tags: keyboard, python, interface

I am using version 12.1.1.0 on OS X 10.13.

Every so often, a Python interpreter cell appears:

[image: python interpreter cell]

I *think* I am probably summoning it by inadvertently pressing ">" (due to clumsy typing). Or maybe some other keyboard shortcut which I haven't discovered is to blame.

Before the interpreter cell appears it often causes a beachball for several seconds, and I find it annoying.

Can I disable the interpreter?

Can I disable all keyboard shortcuts which summon it?

For context, [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207900/how-to-open-a-python-interpreter-input-cell) discusses the interpreter and the keyboard shortcut, but doesn't address how to disable them.

Comment: I also feel like this should be able to be disabled in preferences, as should = summoning Wolfram|Alpha. I'm sure there's a way...not sure why this question has 2 close votes, though.

Comment: try if  `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Input"], 
     StyleKeyMapping -> {"=" -> "WolframAlphaShort", "*" -> "Item"}]},
    StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]` works.

Comment: @kglr thanks, that works! I'll accept it as an answer if you like. (It also addresses thorimur's comment if you remove `"=" -> "WolframAlphaShort",`).

Comment: @kglr is there a way to set this in all notebooks every time I run mathematica?

Comment: @user108903, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short-cut <kbd>></kbd> at the beginning of a line to start an external code cell is set as part of style definitions for `Input` cells:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Input", StyleKeyMapping}]
```

> ```
> {"=" -> "WolframAlphaShort", "*" -> "Item", ">" -> "ExternalLanguage"}
> ```

You can modify the style definitions and remove `">" -> "ExternalLanguage"` to disable this short-cut:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],   
  StyleDefinitions -> 
    Notebook[
     {Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],      
      Cell[StyleData["Input"], 
        StyleKeyMapping -> {"=" -> "WolframAlphaShort", "*" -> "Item"}]},     
  StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]
```

Use `StyleKeyMapping -> {}` to remove all short-cuts associated with `Input` cells.

Comment: How to remove style definitions in all notebook, not only EvaluationNotebook? I was searching this option in Option Inspector but didn't find.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this is how to remove the shortcut by default in all new notebooks.

1. Evaluate

   ```
   CreateDocument@Notebook[{
     Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
     Cell[StyleData["Input"], 
          StyleKeyMapping -> {"=" -> "WolframAlphaShort", "*" -> "Item"}]
     }, StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
   ```
2. Save the resulting notebook to `$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Stylesheets/MyDefault.nb`.
3. In Format>Option Inspector, choose Global Preferences and then search for `DefaultStyleDefinitions` and set it to `"MyDefault.nb"`.
4. Restart Mathematica.

Sources: [@kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/253859/80599), [Quickly editing the stylesheet and saving it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1659/80599)
 and [How do I change my default stylesheet in Mathematica?](https://support.wolfram.com/29974)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

Download Autohotkey.exe from https://www.autohotkey.com/
Then make a script file , put it on the desktop.I call it disableWolfram.ahk. It has two lines, one for each use case mentioned above.

```
^>::return
^=::return
```

Basically this script is disabling <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>. Start Mathematica and then double click on the script.
Keys have been disabled. For a more animated version:

```
^>::return
^=::
Send "You shall not pass"
return
```

[image]

My apologies: I haven't looked into Linux/Mac offerings as I am not working on those systems.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. On OS X at least, the shortcut is just ">", in certain circumstances (e.g., between cells, at the start of a new cell), not "Control+>". So I don't think key remapping will work.